# IOS sending Core Data via e-mail for support-reason

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an app at the app store. Customers reporting bugs. I need the core data from the customers installation to reproduce the error.

What would be the best way in **Objective C** to zip the core data file to a local file on the IOS device and attach that file to an e-mail?

For the moment I am sending the following instruction to the customers to send the core data file but I would like to have a function within the app to do that job just by pressing a button "send support-request".

1.) Download iExplorer (it is free):

https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/download-ie3-mac

2.) Close the app on the iPhone and connect it with your MAC

3.) Start iExplorer
—> Apps —> MyApp —> drag the Documents Folder on the MAC Desktop
—> click it right and Compress it.

Please send me that zip file

Comment: What's your question? How to have the customer send you the data now or how to implement the "Send Data to Support" feature?

Comment: I need help by implementing the function to zip the core data file to a file on the IOS device.

Comment: Then how come your question make no mention of that? You really need to update your question so it focuses solely on what you need help with. And do some searching here and on Google. There are plenty of discussions on zipping files in iOS.

Comment: I just updated the question, thanks!